# iPhone 6 Flexbox Wrapping Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, css, flexbox

I enjoy using flexbox but for some reason I cannot get wrapping to work on any iOS device. Is there an easy fallback for wrapping? Here's an issue where items just won't wrap: ( [JSFiddle Fans](https://jsfiddle.net/f8khw0dL/) )

```css
#flex            {display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;}
#flex .item      {width:33.33%; min-width: 500px; min-height: 300px;}
#flex .one       {background: blue;}
#flex .two       {background: green;}
#flex .three     {background: red;}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
    <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
```

That's the simplest approach. I then tried to add a *ton* of prefixes to everything to see if that helped but it did not:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Is the only solution to **not** use flexbox if I want things to wrap correctly on iphones?

Comment: @Paulie_D That's unfortunate, so there's no real work-around for this? Just stay away from flexbox until IOS <= 6 is phased out? I've been looking online for maybe a JS substitution but haven't found anything substantial.

Comment: @Paulie_D iphone 6 I'm assuming falls under that category, right?

Comment: I guess I assumed iPhone 6 was running iOS 6. The main issue is on the iPhone which looks like should at least be running iOS 8, right? Sorry for the confusion, I am ignorant to how apple does things.

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu I think one of your JSFiddles were right - it seems like percentages were messing up the layout - removed percentages and it seems to work if you want to undelete and revise your answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core of the issue was persistent in iPhone 5 and 6 through all browsers. In the end it had to do with setting a percentage width. Once I removed that everything stacked as it should. I wanna thank [/u/andrei-gheorghiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/andrei-gheorghiu) as his JSFiddles ( in a deleted answer ) pointed me in the right direction.

```css
#flex            {
        display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex; 
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
-webkit-box-direction: normal; 
-webkit-flex-direction: row; 
    -ms-flex-direction: row; 
        flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex .item      {min-width: 200px; min-height: 300px;}
#flex .one       {background: blue;}
#flex .two       {background: green;}
#flex .three     {background: red;}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
    <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would using `width: calc(100% / 3);` work instead of a straight percentage?

Comment: @user500665 I haven't tested it but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work except *maybe* browser support.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 6s not support `flex-direction` tag.
I solved the problem by replacing it with `flex-wrap`.

Old: `flex-direction: column-reverse`

New: `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`

It's work!)

Answer (score 0):

Using only
**display: -webkit-box;**

fixed the problem for me
on iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by giving the flex items `display: inline-block;`

Comment: The issue was on iOS safari not desktop safari. This doesn't solve the said `flex` problem.

Comment: This did solve the problem for me on an iPhone 5 with Safari